# Renaming files in subfolders using zmv

Tags: linux, zsh

Let's say I want to rename all the files inside all the subfolders of a folder from `foo.txt` to `bar.txt` using zmv.

I've tried `zmv '**/foo.txt' 'bar.txt'` but this creates `bar.txt` in the root folder. How can I keep the files in their corresponding subfolder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to reference the directory part in the target. You can do that by putting the wildcards in parentheses and using `$1` to refer to the part matched by the parenthetical group. The `**` wildcard is a little special and requires that the parentheses are around `**/`, no more, no less.

```
zmv '(**/)foo.txt' '${1}bar.txt'
```

You can use the `-w` flag to have each wildcard automatically made into a parenthetical group.

```
zmv -w '**/foo.txt' '${1}bar.txt'
```

Or you can use the `-W` flag and use wildcards in the replacement text — with this flag, the wildcards in the replacement text are turned into `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
zmv -W '**/foo.txt' '**/bar.txt'
```

Alternatively, you can use `$f` to refer to the source path.

```
zmv '**/foo.txt' '$f:r.txt'
```

Comment: the `zmv -W` version is excellent and works exactly as expected.

Comment: Anyway for Zmv to create intermediate directory? For example, I’d like to move from `src/**/foo.txt` to `dst/**/bar.txt`, so the sub-directory under `dst/` might be absent. My current workaround is an `rsync` before a `zmv`.

Comment: @FranklinYu https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59112/preserve-directory-structure-when-moving-files-using-find/59159#59159